# tmux bottom status bar color change

Tags: colors, tmux

I recently started to use `tmux` and like it much, but its green bottom bar is a bit distracting, is there a way to change its color? or a way to hide it?

Answer (score 152, accepted):

There are many options given in the [manual](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1). (See the OPTIONS section.) Create an RC file: `~/.tmux.conf`. The content below enables UTF-8, sets the right TERM type, and draws the status bar with a black background and white foreground.

```
set status-utf8 on
set utf8 on

set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"

set -g status-bg black
set -g status-fg white
```

In FreeBSD 10.1, I had to add `-g` to the UTF directives.

```
set -g status-utf8 on
set -g utf8 on
```

On UTF-8, many SSH clients require one to explicitly define a character set to use. For example, in Putty, select `Window -> Translation -> Remote character set: UTF-8` and select `Use Unicode line drawing code points`.

To turn off the status bar:

```
set -g status off
```

On colors from the manual:

> message-bg colour

> Set status line message background colour, where colour is one of: black, red, green, yellow, blue, magenta, cyan, white, colour0 to colour255 from the 256-colour palette, or default.

So, to list the available colors, first create a [script](https://superuser.com/questions/285381/how-does-the-tmux-color-palette-work), maybe `colors.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
for i in {0..255} ; do
    printf "\x1b[38;5;%smcolour%s\n" "${i}" "${i}"
done
```

Next, execute the script, piping to `less`:

```
colors.sh | less -r
```

This produces a list of colors, 1-255, in this format:

```
colour1
[...]
colour255
```

Pick a color from the list, perhaps *colour240*, a shade of grey. In `~/.tmux.conf`, use this value to set the desired color:

```
set -g status-bg colour240
```

In Fedora 17, 256-color terminals are not enabled by default. The official method used to enable 256-color terminals by default is given on the [Fedora Project Wiki](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/256_Color_Terminals). Follow that guide, or, as a per-user solution, create an alias for tmux to force 256-color support with the "-2" switch.

```
alias tmux="tmux -2"
```

Then start tmux to test it.

Note that, as @ILMostro_7 points out, it would not be correct to set the TERM type for `tmux` from, for example, `~/.bashrc`. Each tmux pane *emulates* a terminal - not the same thing as an xterm. The emulation in `tmux` needs to match "screen," a different terminal description, to behave properly; but, the real terminal does not need to do so. Its description is `xterm-256color`.

Comment: This works fine for Ubuntu, But I Fedora 17 when I set fg color to Gray it says "bad color".

Comment: I used official method from Fedora wiki, and every time I tried to login, returned this error messages:  -bash: $'\r': command not found
-bash: $'\r': command not found
-bash: $'\r': command not found
-bash: /etc/profile.d/256colors.sh: line 13: syntax error near unexpected token `$'in\r''
'bash: /etc/profile.d/256colors.sh: line 13: `  case "$TERM" in   .Also I used the other two method, I run with no error but did not do anything!

Comment: To set bg-color to transparent: `set -g status-bg default`

Comment: Here's the color map: https://github.com/guns/xterm-color-table.vim/blob/master/README.markdown

Example: color260 is orange.

In Tmux, hit Control-b, then `:set -g status-bg colour260`.  (Tmux uses international "colour" vs American "color.")  Also note that Tmux has history, to update the color do Control-b, then `:` to enter command mode, and hit up arrow to edit the last set color command.

Comment: might be a better solution to use `xterm-256color` instead of `screen-256color` for the `TERM` environment variable.

Comment: @ILMostro_7 That's a good catch. Thank you, and I have updated the answer to exclude setting the TERM type for `tmux` from `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: I like black on dark orange `colour166`

Comment: I have done this but still it keep showing `green` background

Answer (score 44):

For me it's

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>
- then enter

  ```
  :set status-style "bg=red"
  ```

Comment: This solution worked for me on my mac with os 10.10.5

Comment: @ReinaAbolofia Great! =D

Answer (score 10):

You can make the status bar transparent. Put this into your `~/.tmux.conf`.

```
set -g status-style bg=default
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Works on macOS. Also the cleanest / simplest of the available solution. And looks good too.

Answer (score 1):

If you are changing `status-style` and it is not applying, take a look at other places in your config, as you might be overriding it somehow.

I had `status-left` and `status-right` with custom fg colors, so `status-style` fg wouldn't apply. Took me a while to find out.