# tmux, TERM and 256 colours support

Tags: terminal, vim, tmux, colors

## Introduction

My question arises from the necessity of understanding **why** I have *now* (after multiple trials) *Terminal* and *tmux* supporting 256 colours and `tput colors` telling me there are only 8 of them.

---

## Background

Let's start from the beginning.

I'm using a *Ubuntu* box, *Guake*, *tmux*, *Vim* and I love the theme *Solarized*. They were looking pretty awful, so I decided to enable the 256 colours support and play a bit around.

Let's see what happens for my *Terminal*. `tput colors` says there are 8 colours. I personally set them to purple, on the left, and *of course* on the right we have 2 different shades of blue. `$TERM` says `xterm`. (To have the coloured `ls` I `eval` [this](https://github.com/seebi/dircolors-solarized/blob/master/dircolors.256dark) in my `.bashrc`.)

[image]

*Vim* also looks fine, despite the fact that I call it with the `256` flag in an environment where 256 colours are **not** supported.

```
set t_Co=256
let g:solarized_termcolors=256
colorscheme solarized
```

The only guy who complains about the reduced colour space is *tmux*. Calling `tmux` provides the "wrong" expected results.

[image]

But calling `tmux` with the `-2` flag makes everything work fine, *magically*.

[image]

Now the only thing that I understand is that `-2` is equivalent of `export TERM=screen-256color` ([source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/60969/38879)).

*Guake* behaves analogously to *Terminal* and both of them answer `xterm` to the question `echo $TERM`.

---

## Question

Basically, does anyone understand why everything works even if it shouldn't?

- *Am I sadistic that I complaining why things work? Maybe.*
- *Is there a better reason? Sure: I'd like to fix the appearance of other Ubuntu boxes in my office, and I'd like to understand why things work or don't work.*

---

## Additional experiments

Running [this script](https://github.com/l0b0/xterm-color-count) (slightly modified) on my `xterm` provides the following result: 256 colours, but only 16 are displayed correctly.

[image]

Then, changing terminal's profile, also these 16 colours change.

[image]

More tests are following.

From left to right, top to bottom, we have *Solarized* colour theme, `dircolor` `ansi-dark` and `256dark`, then default (*Tango*) colour scheme, `dircolor` `ansi-dark` and `256dark`.

[image]

**Observation**: in theory the `dircolor` `ansi-dark` on *Solarized* colour scheme should have match closely the `dircolor` `256dark`. This is not clearly happening for the specific listed files. Instead, this quite happens when in the working directory there are *folders*, *text files* and *symbolic links*. **Conclusion**: no much attention as been paid while encoding the `256dark` colours.

---

## Preliminary conclusions

`xterm` supports 256 colours, despite what `tput colors` says. Programs can refer to the `ansi` palette (customisable by the user) or define their colours, picking from a total of 256 colours.

Comment: Read [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/23789/22222) and the comments below it. Does it answer your question? Also have a look at [this script](https://github.com/l0b0/xterm-color-count) for getting the real number of colors supported.

Comment: Hum... I'm still slightly confused... But, I guess I'm at least understanding that `tput colors` is an unreliable test. Could you check my *preliminary conclusions*?

Comment: My reading of Gilleś's answer is that `tput colors` can only return one value and in terminals that support any of 2,8,16,88 or 256 colors, only the first value (8 in your case) is returned. To get the true value use the script from my last comment. What does that return?

Comment: Check my *Additional experiments* above :)

Comment: Ah, sorry, my bad.

Comment: Then, if I try to run the script from `tmux` it exits with 0 colours :( So, I'm not sure what's happening there...

Answer (score 50, accepted):

There is some information on 256-color support in the [tmux FAQ](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-use-a-256-colour-terminal).

Detecting the number of colors that the terminal supports is unfortunately not straightforward, for historical reasons. See [Checking how many colors my terminal emulator supports](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23763/checking-how-many-colors-my-terminal-emulator-supports/23789#23789) for an explanation. This means that

- tmux cannot reliably determine whether the terminal supports more than 8 colors;
- tmux cannot reliably communicate to the application that it supports more than 8 colors.

When you're in tmux, the terminal you're interacting with is tmux. It doesn't support all of xterm's control sequences. In particular, it doesn't support the `OSC 4 ; …` control sequence to query or set color values. You need to use that while directly running in xterm, outside tmux.

If you run `tmux -2`, then tmux starts with 256-color support, even if it doesn't think that your terminal supports 256 colors (which is pretty common).

By default, tmux advertises itself as `screen` without 256-color support. You can change the value of `TERM` in `.tmux.conf` to indicate 256-color support:

```
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
```

You can use `TERM=xterm-256color` or `TERM=screen-256color` on Ubuntu. These values will only cause trouble if you log in to a remote machine that doesn't have a termcap/terminfo entry for these names. You can copy the entries to your home directory on the remote machine; this works with most modern terminfo implementations.

```
# From the Ubuntu machine to a machine that doesn't have *-256color terminfo entries
ssh somewhere.example.com mkdir -p .terminfo/s .terminfo/x
scp -p /lib/terminfo/s/screen-256color somewhere.example.com:.terminfo/s/
scp -p /lib/terminfo/x/xterm-256color somewhere.example.com:.terminfo/x/
```

Comment: I do appreciate the explanation, but I'm not sure it targets my question.. Well, I agree that my question was quite broad, but I wasn't focusing specifically on *tmux*. Actually, *tmux* was the only guy who was behaving accordingly to expectation. What it was much more mysterious was how `xterm` was able to show me 256 colours even though `tput colors` was saying 8. I guess the answer to this specific question has been addressed by **@terdon** in his comments to the question itself.

Comment: @Atcold It's a long question, but as far as I can tell I've answered it. The non-tmux-related parts are covered by the answer that terdon and I linked to (and that I wrote). Your question would have been a duplicate of that one if it hadn't been for the tmux aspect. What more were you expecting from an answer?

Comment: **@Gilles**, I didn't want to sound mean. I was trying to accredit to **@terdon** the "accepted answer" thing, even though he refers to your answer in another question. Despite this, the `set -g default_terminal "screen-256color"` command is not sufficient to enable the 256 colours in *tmux*. You need to `alias tmux='export TERM=screen-256color; /usr/bin/tmux'` ([reference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10264470/2247039)).

Comment: @Atcold No, the alias isn't needed (I tested). Furthermore this alias wouldn't make sense: it pretends to tmux that it's running inside screen or tmux. However, you do need to run `tmux -2` as per my previous paragraph, if tmux doesn't think your current terminal supports 256 colors, so `alias tmux='tmux -2'` would make sense.

Comment: **@Gilles**, ok, I wasn't clear. Without the `-2` you need to `alias tmux='export TERM=screen-256color; /usr/bin/tmux'` (as it is specified also [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1098/38879)) otherwise, the only `set -g default_terminal "screen-256color"` in `.tmux.cong` does nothing to me. Furthermore, `$TERM` is always `screen`, despite the fact that I manage to have the 256 colours support or not. (Things are working. I am only trying to understand why. Sorry for being this picky.)

Comment: @Atcold That U&L answer has `TERM=xterm-256color tmux`, which is sensible, unlike `TERM=screen-256color tmux`. `tmux -2` is superior because it works even if `screen-256color` isn't in the local terminfo database.

Comment: **@Gilles**, `tmux -2` is **not** superior. Check my findings [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/119988/38879), second **Q/A**.

Comment: For me I had to change the command to `set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"` (- and not _ in default terminal)

Comment: `set -g default-terminal "tmux-256color"` in `~/.tmux.conf` works for tmux 2.7 and fedora 29 without other settings. see [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158508/lose-vim-colorscheme-in-tmux-mode/68982914#68982914)

Comment: If you're using Ubuntu and you're not getting a colored terminal prompt, check your `.bashrc`. In the default `.bashrc` that comes with Ubuntu these days, there's some code that separately decides whether to even *attempt* to add colors. If there's a commented line `#force_color_prompt=yes`, uncomment it and that may resolve it.

Answer (score 35):

I'm impressed about how richfully formatted and detailed the answers (and the question!) are. While they provide valuable info and solutions about the tools you mentioned, they provide very little insight about ***what the heck is going on***, and, most importantly, why things are (somewhat) working for some tools when they supposedly should not.

So here's some insights on your fundamental questions:

- What a terminal *supports* and what it *reports* are different things. Gnome terminal for example is *capable* of displaying 256 colors, but it *announces* itself to the environment (via `$TERM` variable) as an `xterm` emulator (8 color).
- Tools like `tput` follow whatever `TERM` is set to: `tput colors` may print 8, while `env TERM=xterm-256color tput colors` will print 256, regardless if your terminal actually *supports* such capabilities.
- `vim` also follow `TERM` by default, but as *you* told it to use 256 colors (via the flag or the `set t_Co=256`), it will use 256 colors. And it works because your terminal actually *supports* that.
- `tmux`, just like Gnome Terminal, also by default reports itself as an 8-color terminal. But, unlike Gnome Terminal, it only *enables* 256-color capability if you use the `-2` flag, which also makes it *report* itself as an `xterm-256color` compatible emulator.
- `xterm`, as in *the terminal emulator software for the X11*, supports 256 colors, for sure. But `xterm` as in `TERM=xterm` is an 8-color "standard". It means the capabilities of the *original* `xterm`. When it was upgraded to support 256 colors, a long time ago, it coined the `xterm-256color` term for that.

So it all comes down to:

- What capabilities your terminal actually supports (and is enabled to do so)
- How it reports such capabilities to the environment via `TERM`
- How tools interpret `TERM` and adjust themselves accordingly.
- As you can infer from the above, *avoid hammering `export TERM=xterm-256color` in your `~/.bashrc` and such scripts*. As those files are executed regardless of the terminal you're actually using, it will make *all* your terminals, including remote connections from Windows with Putty, Linux console terminal, etc, report themselves as xterm-256color compatible. Which may be true for some but certainly not for all. For example, `getty`, the linux console you access with `CTRL+ALT+1..6`, does not.
- Terminals should report themselves as the "standard" they are most compatible with. If you know they can handle 256 colors, configure them to advertise as such.

Last but not the least, an amazing reading about `TERM` and 256 colors is:

http://blog.sanctum.geek.nz/term-strings/

http://blog.sanctum.geek.nz/256-colour-terminals/

Comment: An example scenario or two would be good additions to this answer.

Comment: @ElijahLynn: I've tried to address the cases OP questioned about, like Vim, tmux and Gnome Terminal. Any other scenarios you suggest?

Answer (score 5):

I will provide a complementary answer which addresses only your additional experiments insofar as they relate to the *solarized directory colors*.

**Setup**

We have the same color output from the test script. The only difference is that I used `lxterminal` on *Openbox* with *slim*, *xcompmgr* and no DM. Therefore I can't easily set a custom palette like you did as that terminal emulator doesn't offer those settings in a GUI and there is no specific [theme](https://github.com/seebi/dircolors-solarized#understanding-solarized-colors-in-terminals) for it (those only exist for a few terminal emulators). So I just use some translucency, undecorated terminals and that blue as foreground color with a blue *Gentoo* background. Since I can't use the *ansi* versions of the color files, I've focused exclusively on getting results with `dircolors.256dark` i.e the "degraded" simple version.

I used the following relevant configuration and the *inconsolata* medium font:

```
echo $TERM
xterm

.bashrc:
eval `dircolors /path/to/dircolors.256dark`

.vimrc:
set t_Co=256
let g:solarized_termcolors=256
syntax enable
set background=dark
colorscheme solarized

.tmux.conf:
nothing at all related to colors!
start tmux with "tmux -2"
```

**Dircolors**

The image below shows what happens both inside and outside of *tmux* with these settings. The first third to the left shows undecorated *lxterminal* windows stacked vertically (3). To the right you have a *tmux* assembly showing the same identical programs(3) I have also included a *solarized* `xterm`<sup>1</sup> showing nano using the .Xresources file included in the [full package](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized) (and sampling it with `xrdb -load ~/.Xresources`):

[image]
*please right click/view image to inspect at full resolution*

The first terminal in the top left corner showcases the default directory colors. Just below is the degraded *solarized* version. Except for the pink on blue background for `.c` files I added, it is identical to what is expected from this(see image below for reference). Compared to the defaults, it builds further on the extended attributes i.e. bold/light/reverse etc. and the colors are different obviously. The default color assignment for `.txt` files in many distribution is green, but it should be grey instead when *solarized*. An *ansi* file rendering a .txt file as green is either not rendering correctly or not rendering at all. The right hand-side results you showed are the correct ones(256dark) in relation to the following reference:

[image]
*solarized "degraded" dircolors* reference map

**Observations**

With the configuration I used, *the results appear identical inside and outside tmux*(I have reversed comments (#) in vi but otherwise the plugin behaves as it should and the multiplexer has no impact on this). Fonts play a huge role in the *solarized* features definition, and a good font is required to maximize the experience. The *solarized* directory colors using the *256dark* file match the reference and requires no specific terminal emulator configuration.

---

**Conclusion**

Actually the *ansi* rendering of the directory colors is just [completely different](https://raw.github.com/huyz/dircolors-solarized/master/img/screen-dircolors-in-iTerm2-solarized_dark.png) from the degraded solarized(256dark). So much so that under *ansi* `.txt` files are green. One cannot be used to validate the rendering of the other. Both solutions need different configuration and produce entirely different results.

Comment: "I don't understand your conclusion about not much attention having been paid to the 256dark encoding where in fact it's the only color file which yields a solarized directory listing?" My confusion arises from the fact that I was considering the `ansi-dark` as correct output (since it's using the non degraded version). Then, if you take as reference the output of the `256dark`, then you have the reversed mindset.

Comment: "With the configuration I used, the results appear identical inside and outside tmux" Sure, if you're using 256 colours, then of course, they will render the same way wherever you have 256 colours support. "It's not clear what the ansi solution would further provide in this context..." The outcome would be having the *true* *Solarized* them (instead of an approximation).

Comment: I understand. I haven't researched the ansi part really so I could not grasp where you were coming from. In any case I found your Q quite enabling thank you. Maybe I'll use vi more now that I find it pretty lol. As for the ansi results, actually now I've seen how it looks... they only showcase that for dir-colors [here](https://raw.github.com/huyz/dircolors-solarized/master/img/screen-dircolors-in-iTerm2-solarized_dark.png). Why the h. do they have different coding under that... I mean I see .txt green... how is grey close to green? I don't understand their project seriously.

Comment: Yeah, I contacted the author personally and the answer is that "it was his personal customisation, since he liked that way". I'm speechless... I'm glad my Q helped someone :)