# Terminal colors for Vim Airline and Tmux Tmuxline

Tags: vim, tmux, colors

When using Vim on its own with Vundle and Airline the theme appears normally:

[image]

When I have loaded it up in Tmuxline, the theme uses different colors and even Vim looks different:

[image]

[image]

Here's my Tmux configuration:

```
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"

source-file /home/tk/.tmux/tmuxline

unbind C-b

set -g prefix C-o

bind | split-window -h
bind - split-window -v

set-window-option -g mode-keys vi

bind-key -t vi-copy 'v' begin-selection
bind -t vi-copy y copy-pipe 'xclip -in -selection clipboard'

bind C-y run "tmux save-buffer - | xclip -selection clipboard"
```

Here's my Vim configuration:

```
set nocompatible " be iMproved, required
filetype off     " required

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
" alternatively, pass a path where Vundle should install plugins
"call vundle#begin("~/some/other/path")

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'gmarik/Vundle.vim'

Plugin 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe'
Plugin 'scrooloose/syntastic'
Plugin 'bling/vim-airline'

Plugin 'godlygeek/tabular'
Plugin 'plasticboy/vim-markdown'

Bundle 'edkolev/tmuxline.vim'

" include plugins here

call vundle#end()
filetype plugin indent on

set backspace=indent,eol,start

set showcmd
set incsearch
set number
set expandtab
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set hlsearch
set ic
set autoindent
set cmdheight=1
set laststatus=2

syntax enable

set nobackup
set noswapfile
set showmatch

" airline
let g:airline_powerline_fonts = 1
let g:airline_theme = 'kolor'

set t_Co=256
```

Obviously, my colors are screwed up somewhere along the line. How do I fix this?

Comment: Your issue makes me think of this [one](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/118806/44370) i.e. the interplay between terminal settings and `tmux`.

Comment: Does `tmux` change the `$TERM` env. variable?

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `tmux -2` to solve this issue.

Comment: Could you add to your answer, an explaination why the tmux config line `set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"`` doesn't do the same as your answer, thank you.

Comment: @XTian In tmux  manual, you can see `-2` option, Force tmux to assume the terminal supports 256 colours. The `set -g default-terminal ` option just only set terminal instead of terminal colors.