# Is it possible to change the color of the tmux status bar in command mode?

Tags: tmux, colors

When I type `Prefix-:` to start typing a command, tmux *changes the color of the status bar to dark yellow*. A similar effect happens if I push `Prefix-,` to change the name of a window.

**Is it possible to control the color that the status bar changes into?**

I have already seen [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60968/tmux-bottom-status-bar-color-change) and searched around the web, but have failed to find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I [reached out](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/3887) on GitHub, and the got the response to use `message-style` option, which I verified to work. Thus, the answer is to put the following in `~/.tmux.conf` to set the background to white.

```
set -g message-style bg=white
```